# Can Python nose tests show wrong value?

Tags: python, unit-testing, assert, nose

I'm running some tests with nose, and it works fine, but in the result, I only see which test on which line failed, not what the wrong value was. For example, I'm running `nosetests -v` and I get this:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: tests.test_convert_to_steer
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/pi/ared/tests.py", line 7, in test_convert_to_steer
    assert convert_to_steer(100, 100) == 100
AssertionError
```

This only tells me which tests failed, but I now have to manually print out the result of `convert_to_steer(100, 100)` to see what the result was.

Does anybody know how it can also give me what the result was on which I get an error?

Comment: If you want the test to give you the result on which you get an error and if you are open to changing the test-runner, you may want to use `pytest` instead of `nose`. See the example here: http://imgur.com/RaWZuu4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your test suite extends `unittest.TestCase`, you can use `self.assertEqual(convert_to_steer(100, 100), 100)`.

For more information, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual).

Comment: I know that, but I love the simplicity of `nose` and using only `assert`. Isn't there a possibility to see this while using simple `assert`s?

Comment: `nose` has nothing to do with using `assert`. There's a reason `unittest` gives these faculties: because they don't exist in another fashion. You can pass a message to `assert`, but it will tell you nothing about the arguments. Try `assert 4 == 5, "Four isn't five"`.

Comment: @kramer65 - `assert` is a keyword and can't be overridden - you get what you get. All `assert` does is check whether an expression (a series of python byte codes) is true. It has no knowledge that a function was called, that a comparison was made or what the return value was. Just the truth value of the single object left over over the dust settles (in your case its simple True or False).